# About Gröbner Bases

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

Recently I have come across a book of Gröbner Bases written by Adams & Loustaunau. The book is excellent and I have become interested in Gröbner bases after reading the book. I want to read more on this subject. Can you recommend me any book? Also tell me about recent research activities of the scholars in this area. What are their targets which are yet to be achieved.

Comment: Looking at [this link](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1996-33-04/S0273-0979-96-00674-X/S0273-0979-96-00674-X.pdf) you can see that another good book is  "Grobner Bases: A computational approach to commutative algebra", by Thomas
Becker and Volker Weispfenning. This is also used by a professor of mine as basic computational algebra book.

Comment: I highly recommend anything by Bernd Sturmfels, in particular *Grobner bases and Convex Polytopes* and *Algorithms in Invariant Theory.*

Answer (score 3):

> - "*Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*" by *David Cox, John Little, Donal O’Shea* . This book introduce Gröbner Bases and use it in various cases, for example in "Elimination Theory".

- "*Commutative Algebra*" by *Eisenbud* (chapter 15)
- "*Monomial Ideals*" by *Herzog-Hibi*

  ---

For recent research activities search **arxiv**. See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62866/recent-applications-of-mathematics/62963#62963)

Comment: they are not exactly the same. they differ in approach or use of Gröbner Bases or ... .